# how to display custom amount in order summary in admin Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.2, adminhtml, order-summary, extrafee, sales-order-view

I have added a custom fee in the order and displayed a custom fee in the checkout order summary.

Similarly, the Custom fee displayed in the order emails in order total summary.

Now I am trying to show the custom fee in summary on the admin order view page.

I have used the below code to display the custom fee on the admin order view page:

**1. sales_order_view.xml**

```
<referenceContainer name="order_totals">
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Totals" name="fee"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

**2. Totals.php**

```
<?php

    
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Sales;

class Totals extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    /**
     * @var \Sivajik34\CustomFee\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $_dataHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency
     */
    protected $_currency;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $dataHelper,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency $currency,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_dataHelper = $dataHelper;
        $this->_currency = $currency;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve current order model instance
     *
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\Order
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
        return $this->getParentBlock()->getOrder();
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getSource()
    {
        return $this->getParentBlock()->getSource();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCurrencySymbol()
    {
        return $this->_currency->getCurrencySymbol();
    }

    /**
     *
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function initTotals()
    {
        $this->getParentBlock();
        $this->getOrder();
        $this->getSource();

        $fee = (int) $this->getSource()->getFee();

        if (!$fee) {
            return $this;
        }
        $total = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject([
            'code' => 'fee',
            'value' => $this->getSource()->getFee(),
            'label' => $this->_dataHelper->getFeeLabel(),
        ]);
        $this->getParentBlock()->addTotalBefore($total, 'grand_total');

        return $this;
    }
}
```

But the custom fee is not showing on the admin order view page. can anyone suggest where I am wrong?

I followed this tutorial [Custom Fee](https://github.com/sivajik34/Custom-Fee-Magento2)

Comment: Have you got custom fee by $this->getSource()->getFee()? Have you checked?

Comment: I think initTotals() is not working...I tried to add log in that function but not working or even use exit but there is no change

Comment: In which path you have added file sales_order_view.xml?

Comment: Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\layout\sales_order_view.xml

Answer (score 0):

Please add like below in Totals.php file

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Sales;
 
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
 
class Totals extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * @var Order
     */
    protected $_order;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\DataObject
     */
    protected $_source;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    public function getSource()
    {
        return $this->_source;
    }
 
    public function displayFullSummary()
    {
        return true;
    }
    public function initTotals()
    {
        $parent = $this->getParentBlock();
        $this->_order = $parent->getOrder();
        $this->_source = $parent->getSource();
        $title = 'Custom Fee';
        $store = $this->getStore();
        if($this->_order->getFee()!=0){
            $customAmount = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
                    [
                        'code' => 'customfee',
                        'strong' => false,
                        'value' => $this->_order->getFee(),
                        'label' => __($title),
                    ]
                );
            $parent->addTotal($customAmount, 'customfee');
        }
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Get order store object
     *
     * @return \Magento\Store\Model\Store
     */
    public function getStore()
    {
        return $this->_order->getStore();
    }
    /**
     * @return Order
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
        return $this->_order;
    }
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getLabelProperties()
    {
        return $this->getParentBlock()->getLabelProperties();
    }
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getValueProperties()
    {
        return $this->getParentBlock()->getValueProperties();
    }
}
```

Please check and let me know on this.

Comment: Not working, still the same issue

Comment: in which magento version you are working?

Comment: Magento version 2.2.4

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please make sure that you are getting your fee value in $this->_order->getFee(). Else please add static fee value 10 and then please check

Comment: I tried even static value but not working and order total section is blank:  https://nimb.ws/wZTubp

Comment: Can you please check error by enabling developer mode?

Comment: Checked in developer mode but there is nothing found in logs

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your first step.
You need to change
`<referenceContainer name="order_totals">`
to

```
<referenceBlock name="order_totals">
```

reference `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml`